# Incorrect datetime value 1292 Laravel 5.7 just from a specific date

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, datetime, laravel-5

I saw this error in questions and answers, but my case is a little bit weird!

I'm using Laravel 5.7 with these database settings:

```
        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

One of my tables records has the user birth date with the `timestamp` format.

This works fine till the user age is smaller than **`1969-02-22 00:00:00`**. It means **`1970-02-22 00:00:00`** is OK, but the first one causes an error!

How can I fix this case?

Comment: I think its not mysql problem. how you save the date to mysql?

Comment: do you use strtotime() in php? How you convert your date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time):

> It is the number of seconds that have elapsed since the Unix epoch, that is the time 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970,

If you have to save dates prior, use another datatype such as `DATE` or `DATETIMTE`.

As you can [read here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html).

Comment: this is not correct for mysql. The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html

Comment: I know, but i mention in the text only **date prior**, and the link provides information for both datatypes, so he can check which he needs and when did you see your birth hour in any form

Comment: @nbk You're right, I did change field to datetime and it's ok now...